# Python - Reset Increment

Tags: python, loops, increment

I have a list of values in a column (A) and want to increment by 1 in column (B) until the value in A changes, however, having difficulty in my loop to reset the increment when A changes.

```
B = []
list_length = len(A)

for i in range(0, list_length):
    j = 1
    while A[i] == A[i+1]:
        B = j
        j += 1
        i += 1
    else:
        B = 1
        j += 1
```

Here is desired output:

| Product(A) | No.(B) |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 |
| Apple | 2 |
| Apple | 3 |
| Orange | 1 |
| Orange | 2 |
| Orange | 3 |
| Orange | 4 |
| Orange | 5 |
| Orange | 6 |
| Melon | 1 |
| Melon | 2 |
| Peach | 1 |
| Peach | 2 |
| Peach | 3 |
| Peach | 4 |

Comment: Please add the contents of list A.

Comment: Is the content of list A always sorted as implied?

Comment: You intend `B` to be an array, but in the loop, you're assigning B to the numbers `j` and `1`. You'd better use `B.append(j)` and `B.append(1)` instead to ADD it to the array instead of changing the variable value.

Comment: Furthermore, the increment of `i` inside the for loop isn't working for you. The next iteration, `i` will be set to the next integer in the range instead of `i + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other two answers are awesome, but I was initially stuck to follow your initial approach with the counter, so here's what I did:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
 
fruit_table = PrettyTable(["Product(A)", "No.(B)"])

products = ["Apple", "Apple","Apple", "Orange","Orange","Orange","Orange","Orange","Melon","Melon", "Peach","Peach","Peach"]

counter = 0
for i in range(0, len(products)-1):

    if products[i] == products[i+1]:
        counter+= 1
        fruit_table.add_row([products[i],counter])
    else:
        fruit_table.add_row([products[i],counter+1])
        counter=0

print(fruit_table)
```

Output:

```
+------------+--------+
| Product(A) | No.(B) |
+------------+--------+
|   Apple    |   1    |
|   Apple    |   2    |
|   Apple    |   3    |
|   Orange   |   1    |
|   Orange   |   2    |
|   Orange   |   3    |
|   Orange   |   4    |
|   Orange   |   5    |
|   Melon    |   1    |
|   Melon    |   2    |
|   Peach    |   1    |
|   Peach    |   2    |
+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through A, and build list B;

```
A = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','d','d']  
B = [1]
for i in range(1,len(A)):
    B.append(B[i-1]+1 if A[i]==A[i-1] else 1)
```

--EDIT--
It's a bit unpythonic though isn't it, looks kinda *C*-ish.

```
A = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','d','d']  
B = [1]
for i,j in zip(A[:-1],A[1:]):
    B.append(B[-1]*(i==j)+1)
```

That's a bit better!

Answer (score 1):

If the list A is sorted such that the re-occurences of an entry are in subsequent indices you could use `np.unique` and simply stack arrays created with `np.arange` as follows:

```py
A = ['Apple','Apple','Apple','Orange','Orange','Orange','Orange','Orange','Orange','Melon','Melon','Peach','Peach','Peach','Peach']  
Aun, cnts = np.unique(A, return_counts=True)
table = np.concatenate([np.stack([np.tile(Aun[i], [n]), np.arange(1, n+1)], axis=1)
                        for i, n in enumerate(cnts)])
```

```
>>>array([['Apple', '1'],
       ['Apple', '2'],
       ['Apple', '3'],
       ['Melon', '1'],
       ['Melon', '2'],
       ['Orange', '1'],
       ['Orange', '2'],
       ['Orange', '3'],
       ['Orange', '4'],
       ['Orange', '5'],
       ['Orange', '6'],
       ['Peach', '1'],
       ['Peach', '2'],
       ['Peach', '3'],
       ['Peach', '4']], dtype='<U21')
```